# How to define a custom EAR file name for a specific application?

Tags: jboss, ear, eclipse-3.4

Here is my setup
SDK: Eclipse Ganymede (3.4.2)
App Server: jBoss 4.2.3GA

I got three projects:

- MYAPP, which is the main project, with only libraries and log4j configurations. This is where application.xml and jboss-app.xml resides.
- MYAPPEJB, which is my business logic project in which I have my entity beans, sessions beans.
- MYAPPWeb, which is my client logic project in which I have my Struts Forms, Struts Actions, JSPs and Jasperreports reports.

When I publish my project to my jBoss server on my laptop, I got the following EAR file name: MYAPP.ear, which make sense.

I would like to define a different custom name for the final EAR, let's say ACCOUNTMANAGER.ear

Here is my application.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="5">
   <display-name>MYAPP</display-name>
   <module>
      <ejb>MYAPPEJB.jar</ejb>
   </module>
   <module>
      <web>
          <web-uri>MYAPPWeb.war</web-uri>
          <context-root>/manager/myapp</context-root>
      </web>
   </module>
   <library-directory>/lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Charles

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your ear file name in application.xml file under web -> web-uri tag. Please check this link for your reference. [web-uri](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs61/programming/app_xml.html#1028735)

Comment: I can't specify a web-uri for my main application. This is only possible for modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify in application.xml file. It will pick up this name instead of ear file name.
MyEarName